# How to set tz string for negative timezones. For example, utc-2.30

Tags: linux, shell, timezone

How to set a tz string for negative time zones in shell script.

For example,
To set a time zone for South Australia(UTC +09:30), below shell script is provided
"export tz=CET-09:30CEST-10:30,M10.1.0/2,M4.1.0/3" in linux command line

In similar way, how to set for Canada -> Newfoundland Time Zone (UTC-2.5) i.e., for negative time zones with day light savings enabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this ?

```
export TZ=CET+02:30CEST+1:30,M10.1.0/2,M4.1.0/3
```